# What is the shortest way to make an equality?

Tags: matches

Ok, I realized that my puzzle was broken and my intended solution didn't work.

I'll leave it there so that the not-so-hard earned answer doesn't go away.

[image: puzzle]

Rules:

1. Round to the nearest hundredth
2. The equal sign need not be aligned.
3. The 1st value can't be an integer

Comment: What does "||||" mean ?

Comment: Does everything have to be in Roman numerals :8

Comment: @klm123 I think it means $\require{cancel}\cancel{||||}-|$. So you might find $||||$ on a wall of a prison cell.

Comment: I did a Google image search for “cuckoo clock face” and [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DwJJQ.png) (originally from [here](http://www.germanclocksandgifts.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/650x/3f6dfe64373715bf8efa3318b0b45ca5/8/t/8t-1151_9-_4_.png)) was the first result.  I had to go down to the 23rd result before I found one that said `IV`.

Answer (score 2):

Can do it in $2$ moves

> Moving an X from the LHS to become a 1/ on the RHS $$\frac{V}{X}=\frac{|}{\frac{||||}{||}}$$

Answer (score 1):

> Move 2 and remove 1:
>
>  $\dfrac{XV}X = \dfrac{III}{II}$